# App Center In-App Update Stuck in a loop iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I have a Xamarin iOS app that I am trying to distribute in the App Center.  It will send out an email and install fine, but when you run it, you get the error

> MyApp.iOS Wants to use "appcenter.ms" to sign in.

I have the option of cancelling or continuing.  I hit continue and it signs in and says In-App Updates are enabled.  It then returns to my app with the message:

> In-App updates disabled.
> This release was either side-loaded or downloaded using a browser in private mode.

I can either Ignore or Reinstall app.  Ignore lets the app work, but it no longer checks for updates.  If I Reinstall app, it opens App Center and I can install it, then it starts back at the beginning.  It is using Safari to do the original install.  I assume that when it does the Reinstall app from within my app, it is using a Safari based browser.  Nothing is in private mode as far as I can tell.  My startup code for App Center is

```
        Distribute.UpdateTrack = UpdateTrack.Private;
        Distribute.DisableAutomaticCheckForUpdate();
        AppCenter.Start("11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555",
               typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Distribute));
```

In my main view, I have the code

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {

        base.ViewDidLoad();

        Distribute.CheckForUpdate();
    }
```

In my Info.plist I have

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>appcenter-11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Cookies are not disabled that I can tell.  I have searched high and low and can't find anything like this.  The only similar issue seemed to be someone messed up the Info.plist.  Can anyone help?

Comment: For questions about App Center, you can go to https://appcenter.ms/apps and click the question mark in the upper right corner and select Constant support. You can ask questions there.

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT I did as you said.  It appears that tech that responded didn't read my entire submission.  I have already done everything in the FAQ and followed the instructions precisely.  There has to be something else that needs to be done that is not mentioned.

Comment: @JimWilcox, did you install the app from App Center? Note that only installed from App Center apps can be updated using App Center in-app updates.

Comment: @DmitriyKirakosyan Yes I installed it from the App Center.  Many times.  I have deleted the app before installing it from the App Center.  I have tried clearing the browser cache then installing it from the App Center to see if possible the cookies were corrupt.  No luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally figured this out.  When I was testing the distribution of my app from the App Center, rather than spam the whole group until it worked, I just distributed it to myself.  This is what caused the problem.  What I had to do was to create another distribution group and only have myself in it. Automatic updates started working once I did this.  The point being is that if you don't distribute it to a group, then it thinks it's side-loaded.